# .NET Core API 502 Bad Gateway on Docker w/ Nginx Proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, asp.net-core

I am hosting a .NET Core web API process in a docker container, with a Nginx reverse proxy.  I can send a request, and I get back the expected responses. There is one issue that I can't seem to figure out.  Every few hours, my API requests begin getting a 502 Bad Gateway error response. If I stop and restart the docker container for the API, the errors stop and everything goes back to normal.

- I'm running .NET Core 2.1.1.
- The host machine for the docker containers is Centos 7.
- I have other containers running as part of this application that do not have problems

Thoughts anybody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I described is fixed. I found that issue resolved itself when I changed my Dockerfile base image.  When updating my API to .NET Core 2.1.1, I decided to use this image in my Dockerfile:
**FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.1-aspnetcore-runtime-alpine3.7**

I changed that line to this:
**FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime**

Using the "dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime" image solves the problem. I can only assume there is something wrong with the "microsoft/dotnet:2.1.1-aspnetcore-runtime-alpine3.7" image.

As a side effect of this switch, my docker image is larger. Previously my docker image was 71mb, but with this change, it is now 107mb. I'm okay with that.